# Time elapsed between two dates

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datetime, if-statement, time

I want to find the exact time elapsed between two dates with a condition that if any value is "0" its measurement units should disappear. for example if hours and minutes are o than the elapsed time should come like 1 day 40 seconds not like 1 day 0 hours 0 minutes 40 seconds.

```
TimeSpan elapsed = completdDate.Subtract(insertdDate);

int daysEl= elapsed.Days;
int hrsEl= elapsed.Hours;
int minsEl = elapsed.Minutes;
int secEl = elapsed.Seconds;

string totalTime = string.Empty;
string days = string.Empty;
string hours = string.Empty;
string mins = string.Empty;
string secs = string.Empty;

if (daysEl == 0 )
    days = days.Replace(daysEl.ToString() , "");
else
  days = daysEl.ToString();

if (hrsEl==0)
    hours = hours.Replace(hrsEl.ToString() , "");
else 
    hours = hrsEl.ToString();

if (minsEl == 0)
    mins = mins.Replace(minsEl.ToString(), "");
else
    mins = minsEl.ToString();

if (secEl == 0)
    secs = secs.Replace(secEl.ToString(), "");
else 
    secs = secEl.ToString();

totalTime = days  + "days" 
          + hours + "hours" 
          + mins  + "minutes" 
          + secs  + "seconds";
```

********************************Output*****************************

[image: Output Image If any value is zero its unit should disappear]

Comment: Use StringBuilder and only add the bits you need.

Comment: Please make more effort to format your code in future.

Comment: If you copy it back into your codebase make sure to praise me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the intermediate strings and if statements:

```
totalTime = 
    (daysEl  == 0 ? "" : (daysEl  + " days "))
  + (hoursEl == 0 ? "" : (hoursEl + " hours "))
  + (minsEl  == 0 ? "" : (minsEl  + " minutes "))
  + (secsEl  == 0 ? "" : (secsEl  + " seconds "));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to omit zero values, you're more likely looking at a formatting issue, not a calculation one, and it might be easier to use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

if (elapsed.Days != 0)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} days ", elapsed.Days);
if (elapsed.Hours != 0)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} hours ", elapsed.Hours);
if (elapsed.Minutes != 0)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} minutes ", elapsed.Minutes);
if (elapsed.Seconds != 0)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} seconds ", elapsed.Seconds);

if (sb.Length == 0)
    return "instant!";

// get rid of the last space in there!
return sb.ToString().Substring(0,sb.Length-1);
```

By using a format, you're able to more succinctly bind the value with the units (ie "14 seconds") and thus put the whole portion into an if statement, bypassing the section entirely if it's zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

    int daysEl= elapsed.Days;
    int hrsEl= elapsed.Hours;
    int minsEl = elapsed.Minutes;
    int secEl = elapsed.Seconds;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (daysEl != 0 )
        sb.Append(daysEl + " days ");
    if (hrsEl != 0)
        sb.Append(hrsEl + " hours ");
    if (minsEl != 0)
        sb.Append(minsEl + " mins ");   
    if (secEl != 0)
        sb.Append(secEl + " secs ");

    string totalTime = sb.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine (totalTime);
}
```

Comment: if I read this right you will get exactly 1 Day (if your system is any good ;)) ... and of course it's the same as Aravol's answer

Comment: is it wrong?  some might say my answer more closely resembles the OP's code which will make it easier to comprehend given his/her level...

Comment: it's not wrong - but normaly you want not n-times the same basic answer here - no offense man